# show hide descriptions for buttons

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to have a function that when you click on the button it will display the definitions of the respective letters. Like when you click the button D, it should display designated definition.

```css
#container {
  text-align: center;
}

.button {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 7px 17px;
  cursor: pointer;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  outline: none;
  color: #fff;
  background-color: red;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 15px;
  box-shadow: 0 5px #323;
  height: auto;
  width: auto;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.button:hover {
  background-color: #DB1023
}

.button:active {
  background-color: #A30406;
  box-shadow: 0 5px #333;
  transform: translateY(4px);
```

```html
<button class="button">A</button>
<button class="button">B</button>
<button class="button">C</button>
<button class="button">D</button>
<button class="button">E</button>
<button class="button">F</button>
<button class="button">G</button>
<button class="button">H</button>
<button class="button">I</button>
<button class="button">J</button>
<button class="button">K</button>
<button class="button">L</button>
<button class="button">M</button>
```

Comment: That's a wrong syntax.

Comment: what do you mean? what syntax are you referring to?

Comment: Check out my answer. The whole syntax of HTML is wrong, and CSS is unclosed.

Comment: sorry, I didn't see that you had edited the code. So, what I am trying to do is a glossary page, so each letter will have 3 or more definitions. I want to have the buttons like a menu on top and once you click each button will display a div with the definitions.

Comment: Did you check my answer? Are you looking for something similar to that?

Comment: I did, however as I mentioned, letter A will have 3 definitions, so where should I add the paragraphs?

Comment: I didn't understand that. So the answer is, yes! Please add `<br />`s or paragraphs...

Comment: yes, I did check your answer, and I am looking for something similar

Comment: formatted code into a code-snippet

Answer (score 0):

I'll do something like this:

```js
var letters = {
  "A": "A Definition.",
  "B": "B Definition.",
  "C": "C Definition.",
  "D": "D Definition.",
  "E": "E Definition.",
  "F": "F Definition.",
  "G": "G Definition.",
  "H": "H Definition.",
  "I": "I Definition.",
  "J": "J Definition.",
  "K": "K Definition.",
  "L": "L Definition.",
  "M": "M Definition.",
  "N": "N Definition.",
  "O": "O Definition.",
  "P": "P Definition.",
  "Q": "Q Definition.",
  "R": "R Definition.",
  "S": "S Definition.",
  "T": "T Definition.",
  "U": "U Definition.",
  "V": "V Definition.",
  "W": "W Definition.",
  "X": "X Definition.",
  "Y": "Y Definition.",
  "Z": "Z Definition."
};
var finalHTML = "";
Object.keys(letters).forEach(function(l) {
  finalHTML += '<div><button title="' + letters[l] + '">' + l + '</button><span>' + letters[l] + '</span></div>';
});
document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = finalHTML;
```

```css
button {
  padding: 3px 5px;
  width: 25px;
  margin: 5px;
}

span {
  display: none;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

button:active+span,
button:focus+span {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div id="output"></div>
```